# How to map an object to arrays so it can be converted to csv?

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to convert an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "123" : "abc",
  "231" : "dbh",
  "452" : "xyz"
}
```

To csv that looks like this:

```
"123","abc"
"231","dbh"
"452","xyz"
```

I would prefer to use the command line tool [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) but can't seem to figure out how to do the assignment. I managed to get the keys with `jq '. | keys' test.json` but couldn't figure out what to do next.

The problem is you can't convert a k:v object like this straight into csv with `@csv`. It needs to be an array so we need to convert to an array first.  If the keys were named, it would be simple but they're dynamic so its not so easy.

Comment: Why not just gsub ':' for ',' ?

Comment: google `JSON  to csv` ...lots of results

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try this filter:

```
to_entries[] | [.key, .value]
```

- `to_entries` converts an object to an array of key/value objects.  `[]` breaks up the array to each of the items in the array
- then for each of the items, covert to an array containing the key and value.

This produces the following output:

```
[
  "123",
  "abc"
],
[
  "231",
  "dbh"
],
[
  "452",
  "xyz"
]
```

Then you can use the `@csv` filter to convert the rows to CSV rows.

```
$ echo '{"123":"abc","231":"dbh","452":"xyz"}' | jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @csv'
"123","abc"
"231","dbh"
"452","xyz"
```

Comment: Hmm. For me this returns "`\"123\",\"abc\""` etc. I.e. each row is additionally quoted.

Comment: Make sure you add the `-r` flag to the call.  You'll want to get the raw output.

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked that.

Comment: How do you use `to_entries` to a hash in the middle of JSON? All examples I've ever seen assume the target hash is at root.

Answer (score 5):

Jeff answer is a good starting point, something closer to what you expect:

```
cat input.json | jq 'to_entries | map([.key, .value]|join(","))'

[
 "123,abc",
 "231,dbh",
 "452,xyz"
]
```

But did not find a way to join using newline:

```
cat input.json | jq 'to_entries | map([.key, .value]|join(","))|join("\n")'

"123,abc\n231,dbh\n452,xyz"
```

Comment: "\n" is the JSON representation of newline; to see it as a literal newline, use the -r command-lline option of jq.  However, in general, using `@csv` to get CSV is the better way to go as @csv really does produce valid CSV.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example I ended up using this morning (processing PagerDuty alerts):

```
cat /tmp/summary.json | jq -r '
  .incidents
  | map({desc: .trigger_summary_data.description, id:.id})
  | group_by(.desc)
  | map(length as $len
  | {desc:.[0].desc, length: $len}) 
  | sort_by(.length) 
  | map([.desc, .length] | @csv)
  | join("\n") '
```

This dumps a CVS-separated document that looks something like:

    `"[Triggered] Something annoyingly frequent",31
    "[Triggered] Even more frequent alert!",35
    "[No data] Stats Server is probably acting up",55`

Answer (score 1):

Try This 
give same output you want

```
echo '{"123":"abc","231":"dbh","452":"xyz"}' | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | "\"" + .key + "\",\"" + (.value | tostring)+ "\""'
```

Answer (score -3):

```
onecol2txt () {
 awk 'BEGIN { RS="_end_"; FS="\n"}
   { for (i=2; i <= NF; i++){
       printf "%s ",$i 
       }
     printf "\n" 
   }'
}
cat jsonfile | jq -r -c '....,"_end_"' | onecol2txt
```