# Iterate over a json using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, jq

I have a json in the following format. I want to iterate over this json file

```
 {
     "atest_engine": { "version": "96" }, 
     "a_kdfvm": { "version": "68" }, 
     "aseft_api": { "version": "" },
     "push_psservice": { "version": "68" },
   }
```

I tried jq utility and my script is as follows.

```
count=$( jq '. | length' test.json )
echo $count
for((i=0;i<$count;i++)) 
do 
 name=$(cat test.json | jq '.|keys['${i}']')
 version=$(cat test.json | jq '.|keys['${i}'].version')
 echo $name
 echo $version
done
```

I am getting count and name properly but not able to fetch version information. How can I get it. I am new to scripting and any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, maybe shell isn't a right tool for the task? Have you considered alternatives like e.g. python?

Comment: no. i want to do it using shell script. i know its possible with jq or similar utilities. i am just facing compile errors

Comment: If you insist on using shell script, then at least learn the basics of shell scripting.  [Unquoted variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) and [useless uses of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) are grave shell scripting antipatterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First up your JSON example seems slightly malformed - the push_psservice line has a comma after it but this is most likely a typo.

You might find it easier to turn your object's fields into an array using jq's to_entries (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254365/4513656 ) e.g.:

```
to_entries | .[0].key
to_entries | .[0].value.version
```

Try this on https://jqplay.org/ .

Answer (score 4):

### input.json

```
{
     "atest_engine": { "version": "96" }, 
     "a_kdfvm": { "version": "68" }, 
     "aseft_api": { "version": "" },
     "push_psservice": { "version": "68" }
}
```

### command

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)\t\(.value.version)"' input.json |
  while read name version
  do
    echo "name:" $name
    echo "version:" $version
  done
```

### result

```
name: atest_engine
version: 96
name: a_kdfvm
version: 68
name: aseft_api
version:
name: push_psservice
version: 68
```